# using dictionary to replace words in sentence in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I am trying to replace words in a sentence in dataframe by a dictionary. How can I replace the original dataframe?

The dictionary : rep_vocab contains `{wrong words: correct words}`
dataframe: data_test
column['question1'] the sentences
column['d5'] contains a set of words which is misspelling in the sentences.i use this column to quickly locate the row of sentences which has wrong words.

My code:

```
data_test.loc[data_test['d5']!=set()['question1'].replace(rep_vocab,regex=True)
```

It returns the right result, but the original value in dataframe doesn't change.
I tried other ways like use `inplace=True`, but it raised a warning:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Answer (score 0):

You can just take the output and insert it (so not doing it inplace).

```
data_test.loc[data_test['d5']!=set()['question1'] = data_test.loc[data_test['d5']!=set()['question1'].replace(rep_vocab,regex=True)
```

But please check if you need the condition, You might be able to just type:

```
data_test['question1'] = data_test['question1'].replace(rep_vocab,regex=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the second solution works. However, there are more than one million rows of sentences.  Some of them do not contain wrong words, so I USE column[D5] to make a slice. So I prefer the first solution! (there may be some mistakes in the code)

Comment: Try to compare the speed of the two. For readability I would strongly prefer the second.